# How to handle long sentences without spaces in IE and firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is part of an asp.net page.

```
<style>
.container-multiline{
display: table;
}
.row-multiline{
display: table-row;
}
.left-multiline, .right-multiline{
display: table-cell;
}
.examCellRight{
border: none; padding:0
}
.examCellLeft{
border: none;
width: 90px;
padding:0;
}
.exam-comment-label{
width: 88px;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: top;
text-align: right;
}
.examCellCommentRight{
border: none; padding-left:5px
}
.exam-comment-data{
border: none; padding-left: 5px
}
.wrap-long-word{
        max-width: 490px; 
        word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>

<div class="container-multiline">
                <div class="row-multiline">
                    <div class="left-multiline examCellLeft exam-comment-  label">
                        <label  class="exam-label- color">Comments:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-multiline examCellCommentRight exam-comment-data wrap-long-word">
                        <label  >Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongcontinuoussentence!</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is in the label which displays a loooong sentence without any space. The issue happens only in IE and FireFox and not in Chrome. In such cases, the sentence goes beyond the boundary. The max-width: 490px; and word-wrap: break-word; within the wrap-long-word class fixes it, but the issue is now it is not resizable. For example with this width, it doesn't cover the entire available width. I tried to change the label element with div or span, still didn't work
Thanks

Comment: For maximum compatibility, use the CSS property `word-break: break-all;`. It will split the words when they are too lengthy.

Comment: This resolved my issue and was a life saver. Thanks! Not sure how to mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`word-wrap: break-word` is only compatible with the most recent versions of each browser. To ensure backwards compatibility (to IE8), use `word-break: break-all;` in conjunction or in place of `word-wrap`.